# How can I make Apache 2.4 recognize a .htaccess that is a symbolic link?

Tags: apache-2.4, symbolic-link

```
$ ls -l .htaccess
lrwxrwxrwx 1 suseika suseika 74 Oct  1 03:35 .htaccess -> /home/suseika/some/path/to/the/actual/.htaccess
```

Apache just ignores such .htaccess. If I create a file instead of a symbolic link, it works properly. Can I configure Apache 2.4 to use that symlinked .htaccess?

Comment: Does the user that apache is running as have access to that file, including the ability to traverse that path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had doesn't have anything to do with apache config. I run apache in a Docker container, and the symbolic link pointed to a file that is not available in that container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the following of symlinks with the [Options directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options)

Comment: It is already enabled